# Overloading compound-assignment-operator in C++ does not change variable

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, compound-assignment

In order to become more familiar with C++, I'm implementing a class to manipulate complex numbers.

```
class Complex {
    private:
        double _real;
        double _imag;

    public:
        Complex();
        Complex(double real, double imag);
        Complex(const Complex& z);

        Complex operator+(const Complex& u) const;
        Complex operator+=(const Complex& u);
};
```

I already overloaded the `+` operator which works as expected:

```
Complex Complex::operator+(const Complex& u) const {
    Complex z(_real + u._real, _imag + u._imag);
    return z;
}

u=1-2i
v=2-1i
u+v=3-3i
```

In addition, I wanted to overload `+=` as well:

```
Complex Complex::operator+=(const Complex& u) {
    Complex z(_real + u._real, _imag + u._imag);
    return z;
}
```

This however, does not work as expected and the result of `u+=v` is `u=1-2i`. Why is that the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compound assignment operator creates a new object z instead of changing the original object.

Declare the operator within the class definition like

```
Complex & operator+=(const Complex& u);
```

and define it the following way

```
Complex & Complex::operator+=(const Complex& u) {
    _real += u._real;
    _imag += u._imag;

    return *this;
}
```

The operator can be defined as a non-class friend function. For example

```
class Complex {
    private:
        double _real;
        double _imag;

    public:
        Complex();
        Complex(double real, double imag);
        Complex(const Complex& z);

        Complex operator+(const Complex& u) const;
        friend Complex & operator+=(Complex &v, const Complex& u);
};
Complex & operator+=(Complex &v, const Complex& u)
{
    v._real += u._real;
    v._imag += u._imag;

    return v;
}
```

Comment: That helped a lot. Why do you return the result by reference?

Comment: @Samuel Because that's what `operator+=` is supposed to do. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading?rq=1.

Comment: @Samuel In C++ opposite to C the assignment operator returns lvalue reference. For example in C++ you can write int x = 1; int y = 10; ( x += y ) *= 10;

Answer (score 1):

First of all assign like operators should return reference to assigned value.

Secondly your code should change value of current object.

There are couple solutions:

```cpp
Complex& Complex::operator+=(const Complex& u) {
    *this = Complex(_real + u._real, _imag + u._imag);
    return *this;
}
```

Or

```cpp
Complex& Complex::operator+=(const Complex& u) {
    _real += u._real;
    _imag += u._imag;

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Which solution is the better one?

Comment: from compiler perspective there is no difference ("as if" rule). So just personal preference.